# How to remove a cookbook version constraint in a given environment?

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

We use Chef Server ver 11 with two different environments - dev and staging.  The cookbook version in the staging environment is restricted to a specific version so all nodes under the environment is unaffected with my changes.

- Staging Environment

`mycookbook = 0.6.2`

Now, I verified my cookbook changes for a given node in dev environment  (where no version restrictions enabled).

How do I remove the version constraint in staging environment defined above?. I only see the option to update the constraint via management console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you would not remove the constraint, you would increment/change the version pinned in your staging environment once it is tested in dev.

The common method for managing the environment is by keeping your environment files in a source control repository and then uploading them to the server using knife.

you can download them using:

```
knife download environments
```

and make your edits to the environment file you want to change, commit to your source control and then upload them to the server using:

```
knife upload environments/staging.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [knife environment from file](https://docs.chef.io/knife_environment.html#from-file) to upload the modified environment file (that you should track in VCS instead of modifying it in the chef server).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with duckworth that using source control is better, but if you want to edit in place, you can use `knife environment edit <env name>` and then simply delete the constraint for that particular cookbook.